# How can I uninstall software based on version number being less than a certain value in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

I would like to remove all 7-zip software less than version 16.00 and install the latest version. If a version higher than 16 exists then do nothing.

I have tried to do this using Group Policy Objects in the software installation option for software settings in computer configuration. The group policy object appears in the RSoP of the machine but there is a yellow exclamation next to the item in the gpedit.msc settings on the test machine.

As per Rabbid10's suggestion I have tried the following:

```
$AllRegAppEntries = Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall,HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.pspath}

$FilteredApps = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

foreach ($App in $AllRegAppEntries) {
    if ($App.DisplayName -ilike "*7-Zip*") {

        try {
            $DisplayVersionAsVersion = New-Object System.Version $App.DisplayVersion
        } catch {
            $DisplayVersionAsVersion = New-Object System.Version
        }

        $VersionToCheck = New-Object System.Version "16.0.0.0"

    echo "versionToCheck is:"
    echo $versionToCheck

    echo "DisplayVersionAsVersion is currently: "
    echo $DisplayVersionAsVersion


        if ($DisplayVersionAsVersion -gt $VersionToCheck) {
            [void]$FilteredApps.Add($App)
        }
    }
}

Echo "last part of script"

foreach ($App in $FilteredApps) {
    echo "Hi, Im in the uninstall section"
    # Make sure uninstall string uses MSIEXEC
    if ($App.UninstallString -ilike "msiexec*") {
        $GUID = $App.UninstallString.Substring($App.UninstallString.IndexOf("{"))
        $GUID = $GUID.Substring(0, $GUID.IndexOf("}") + 1)
        Write-Host "Running the following command: msiexec.exe /x $GUID /qn /norestart"
        Start-Process "msiexec.exe" "/x $GUID /qn /norestart" -Wait
    }
}
```

And my output looks like this:

[image]

Comment: When I did this, I simply uninstalled the lower versions and it kept running.  But I was prepared to keep uninstalling them all and just install the latest if it had not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you effectively have to search the registry Uninstall keys for the product you want to remove, by name and version.  You can use PowerShell to do this by first grabbing all installed applications with using [Get-ChildItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem):

```
$AllRegAppEntries = Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall,HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.pspath}
```

Once you have all of the entries, you can filter them based on **DisplayName** and **DisplayVersion**.  To do this, you can do something like this:

```
$FilteredApps = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

foreach ($App in $AllRegAppEntries) {
    if ($App.DisplayName -ilike "*7-Zip*") {

        try {
            $DisplayVersionAsVersion = New-Object System.Version $App.DisplayVersion
        } catch {
            $DisplayVersionAsVersion = New-Object System.Version
        }

        $VersionToCheck = New-Object System.Version "16.0.0.0"

        if ($DisplayVersionAsVersion -lt $VersionToCheck) {
            [void]$FilteredApps.Add($App)
        }
    }
}
```

After you have all of the apps that match your search criteria, you will need to get the GUIDs of those apps.  You can get this from the **UninstallString** of the registry item.  Once you have GUID, you should be able to uninstall the product [Start-Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) and passing the GUID to [msiexec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490936.aspx) with uninstall parameters:

```
foreach ($App in $FilteredApps) {
    # Make sure uninstall string uses MSIEXEC
    if ($App.UninstallString -ilike "msiexec*") {
        $GUID = $App.UninstallString.Substring($App.UninstallString.IndexOf("{"))
        $GUID = $GUID.Substring(0, $GUID.IndexOf("}") + 1)
        Write-Host "Running the following command: msiexec.exe /x $GUID /qn /norestart"
        Start-Process "msiexec.exe" "/x $GUID /qn /norestart" -Wait
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

**UPDATE: Tweaked code to look for app before trying to get version, etc.**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I run the lines in the first half of your answer, I get the following error message: New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Version string portion was too short or too long." It does this for each program in my uninstall list.

Comment: Sorry about that. I should have actually ran the code before typing it above. See the update. Ideally, you'll throw these different processes into functions that are parameterized, but if not, this should work for what you asked for.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I have tried the script again with debugging. It looks as though the script gets through the first foreach loop okay but does not enter the second part. I put an echo in after 'foreach($App in $FilteredApps) {' and I don't see it. The version of 7-Zip I have installed on the device as a test is 7-zip 9.20

Comment: Ah...  You know, you found one more typo. Above, it's checking the version in the "foreach ($App in $AllRegAppEntries)" section.  I was looking for versions above 16.0.0.0 because I have 16.4 on my machine.  I changed it to look for versions below...

Comment: Hi Rabbid. Thank you for your response. This has worked perfectly. You have inspired me to learn Powershell. :)